# Set Detailed Bluetooth Audio Codec preferences in macOS Monterey

Tags: audio, bluetooth, plist, defaults, monterey

#### TL;DR

Preferences set in `~root/Library/Preferences/bluetoothaudiod.plist` don't seem to have any effect any more. “Bluetooth Explorer” and `defaults(1)` commands that messed with these don’t seem to work either. **Does anyone know how to go about doing these things in Monterey?**

---

Historically, we pedants and audiophiles on macOS have been able to tweak `bluetoothaudiod.plist` to our own fancy. We were essentially restricted to setting AAC bitrates, toggling AptX (not AptX *HD*, mind you), and packet buffer limits and stuff, but it was *still **something**.*

The way to go about this in GUI was to use *“Bluetooth Explorer”*, an Xcode "extra" that is last known to have been distributed with Xcode 11.
Of course, one could always use `defaults(1)` as well.

---

As [GianpaoloPascasi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/440721/gianpaolo-pascasi) points out in a post below, **tweaking BT-audio codecs can [sometimes be a necessity](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431341/418296).**
How does one tweak the stuff that *Bluetooth Explorer* and `bluetoothaudiod.plist` managed, in Monterey?

Comment: Asking whether things still work usually results in answers which aren't really helpful. Can you edit the question to ask for solutions for the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the heads up! On it

Comment: Yeah you're right thanks for pointing it out @nohillside . Tried to make it better, cut down on all my rambling

Comment: The only alternative right now is to downgrade to Big Sur and use BlueTooth Explorer or Terminal Commands. My headphones are SBC codec only and would not stay connected when macOS was trying to connect via AAC. I think more and more Apple wants to push users to their products so they're closing down lanes to tweak and compensate for 3rd party products.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm! Bluetooth explorer and the terminal commands (sudo defaults write bluetoothaudiod) are not working, giving no errors.
I saw that in /Library/Preferences/ there is an empty plist file "com.apple.Bluetooth.plist"...

P.S.

I started searching because i have a brand new pair of Xiaomi Earbuds Basic 2 and they often loss connection, they sound very weird when using their microphone and sometimes the sound playing even "jumps". All of this on a Macbook Pro 13" 2020. I'd like to go back to BigSur and try out the Bluetooth explorer...
Obviusly, they work good on my Windows laptop and on my phone.

The worst thing is that a lot of tutorials cover old methods (putting the keyword "Monterey" SUCH WOW) no longer working. Thanks Apple for this st_pid sh_t.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked. Well, it does in a way, but the question itself is badly written.

Comment: @nohillside yes, my bad. Anyway this is the only useful post i found on the web.

Comment: Nah, _my_ bad really 
Anyhoo, thanks for making those edits! And thanks @nohillside for approving them
Went back and cleaned up my post. Hope it's better now